# Select records created in a 24 hour time-frame

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to query our database to find all records that were created between 6am yesterday and 6am today. This will be run in a report at any point during the day so set times/dates are useless.

I have this so far:-

```
SELECT * FROM DaySummaryDetail DSD
WHERE DSD.FromDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, GetDate()) 
AND DATEADD(Day, 1, GetDate())
```

But obviously this only works for 24 hours ago from right now until right now. I can't figure out how to apply a time as well as date.

Every example I find online seems slightly different and uses set dates/times ie, `>= 20/02/2015 06:00:00`.

I normally use Oracle SQL which would simply work using this:-

```
ptt.mod_date_time >= TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) - 2 / 24
AND ptt.mod_date_time <= TRUNC (SYSDATE - 1) + 22 / 24
```

This would return results from 10pm to 10pm but the format appears totally different in SQL Server.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sorry i should have added that! It's 2012. Titled edited!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `datetime` values you are after by doing the following:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()))) Today6AM,
       DATEADD(HOUR,-18,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()))) Yesterday6AM
```

By doing this: `CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE())` you are stripping off the time portion of today's date. Converting it back to `datetime` gives you midnight for today.

The query adds 6 hours to midnight of the current day for 6am today and subtracts 18 hours from midnight of the current day to give you 6am on the previous day.

**Output:**

```
Today6AM                 Yesterday6AM
================================================
2015-02-20 06:00:00.000  2015-02-19 06:00:00.000
```

So adding that to your query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DaySummaryDetail DSD
WHERE DSD.FromDateTime 
      BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR,-18,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE()))) 
          AND DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE ,GETDATE())))
```

Comment: thanks for this - i was thinking for a moment that your answer didn't work, the -18 just needed to be first before the 6. Your anwser was really clear and easy to read and solves my problem perfectly. Really appreciate the example using my code, made applying this to what i'm doing much easier. Thanks!

Comment: @LuckySevens no problem, happy to help. Have updated post with between clause fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartTimestamp          datetime
DECLARE @EndTimestamp            datetime
DECLARE @HourPartOfSearchRange   nvarchar(6)

SET @HourPartOfSearchRange       = ' 06:30'
SET @StartTimestamp              = 
CAST((CONVERT(varchar(11), DATEADD(DAY,-1,@CurrentUTCDateTime), 106) + @HourPartOfSearchRange) AS datetime)

SET @EndTimestamp                = 
CAST((CONVERT(varchar(11), @CurrentUTCDateTime, 106) + @HourPartOfSearchRange) AS datetime)
```

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test Where Timestamp Between @StartTimestamp AND @EndTimestamp

Answer (score 1):

today 6am is

```
dateadd(hour,6,cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

`cast(getdate() as date)` truncates the timepart, cast it back as datetime because dateadd won't add hours otherwise and add 6hours

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be like so:

```
select  *
from DaySummaryDetail DSD
where DSD.FromDateTime between cast(cast(cast(getdate()-1 as date) as varchar(30)) + ' 06:00:00.000' as datetime)
    and cast(cast(cast(getdate() as date) as varchar(30)) + ' 06:00:00.000' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help ...

```
SELECT DATEADD( hour, 6, CAST(CAST(GETDATE(), AS Date) AS DateTime) ) AS 'Today@6am'
SELECT DATEADD( hour, 6, CAST(CAST(GETDATE()-1, AS Date) AS DateTime) ) AS 'Yesterday@6am'
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use [`SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213396(v=sql.110).aspx) to construct a datetime value that is today at 6am like this:

```
SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), 6, 0)
```

**Output:** `2015-02-20 06:00:00`

then you can use the above expression in place of `GETDATE()` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @TodayAt6AM DATETIME = SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 
                                                      MONTH(GETDATE()), 
                                                      DAY(GETDATE()), 
                                                      6, 
                                                      0)
SELECT * 
FROM DaySummaryDetail DSD
WHERE DSD.FromDateTime BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, @TodayAt6AM) AND     
                               DATEADD(Day, 1, @TodayAt6AM)
```